# Play 1.2.4 findByID not working for composite Id

Tags: java, playframework, crud, playframework-1.x

I have a composite primary key in my DB table. The method findByID accepts the id and returns the entity. I am not sure how to implement this method for accepting an composite Id and returning the corresponding entity.

The composite ID is implemented using @EmbeddedID annotation.

Kindly let me know on this.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using embedded id then you have to override equals and hashCode method of object 
example:
model class:

```
public class ModelClass extends GenericModel {

@EmbeddedId
public EmbeddedPK embeddedPK = new EmbeddedPK ();
.
.
.
}
```

embedded primary key class:

```
@Embeddable
public class EmbeddedPK implements Serializable {
//default serial version id, required for serializable classes.
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="col1_id",nullable=false,updatable=false)
public Col1 col1;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="col2_id",nullable=false, updatable=false)
public Col2 col2;

    public boolean equals(Object other) {
    if (this == other) {
        return true;
    }
    if (!(other instanceof EmbeddedPK)) {
        return false;
    }
    EmbeddedPK castOther = (EmbeddedPK)other;
    return 
        (this.col1 == castOther.col1)
        && (this.col2 == castOther.col2);

}

public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int hash = 17;
    hash = hash * prime + ((int) (this.col1 ^ (this.col1 >>> 32)));
    hash = hash * prime + ((int) (this.col2 ^ (this.col2 >>> 32)));

    return hash;
}

}
```

by the above approach you can make embedded id and get the get the corresponding entity.

but the alternate best approach is to use GenericModels GenerationType.AUTO.
Example:

```
    @Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "entity_id")
public Long id;
```

and make your set of column unique by adding below code above your entity class

```
  @Table(name="example", uniqueConstraints=@UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"col_1", "col_2"}))
  })
```

this approach is more easy to fetch corresponding entity.

Answer (score 0):

The key is to decide on a string representation for your composite id.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19278569/1369495 has an example that might point you in the right direction.